# Linking source installed pandas to homebrew'd python

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to install the python package `pandas`.

All my existing python gear has been installed using home-brew / easy_install / pip, however pip and easy_install both fail on `pandas` -- claiming that i do not have numpy > 1.6 (though when in python `numpy.__version__` returns 1.6.2).

Despite this `pip install numpy --upgrade` reports that I am up-to-date.

To hack around this, I git-cloned the source code down, and ran `python setup.py install` in my `/Library/Python/...` directory.  It seemed to build okay, however when i import pandas, i get an error and i'm not sure what to do about it.

Can anyone help me link the compiled library to my existing install?

The error follows:

```
dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.9.1.dev_5a152bd-py2.7-macosx-10.7-x86_64.egg/pandas/lib.so, 2): Symbol not found: _floatify
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.9.1.dev_5a152bd-py2.7-macosx-10.7-x86_64.egg/pandas/lib.so
Expected in: flat namespace
in /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.9.1.dev_5a152bd-py2.7-macosx-10.7-x86_64.egg/pandas/lib.so
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.9.1.dev_5a152bd-py2.7-macosx-10.7-x86_64.egg/pandas/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
import pandas.lib as lib
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.9.1.dev_5a152bd-py2.7-macosx-10.7-x86_64.egg/pandas/lib.so, 2): Symbol not found: _floatify
Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.9.1.dev_5a152bd-py2.7-macosx-10.7-x86_64.egg/pandas/lib.so
Expected in: flat namespace
in /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.9.1.dev_5a152bd-py2.7-macosx-10.7-x86_64.egg/pandas/lib.so
```

Comment: This problem's solution was to delete the version of numpy found in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python`.  To figure this out i had to `brew uninstall python`, and use the system python to `import numpy` and then `print numpy.__version__` -- which confirmed that it was the old one. I think identified the location of the crusty bumpy via `print(numpy)`, and finally `cd`'d into the directory and `sudo rm -r numpy`. Only after this was done would `pip install pandas` work -- meaning i did not need to `git clone` it down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was discussed and resolved on GitHub: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2188. The issue had to due with Clang's C99 behavior w.r.t. inline C functions.

Comment: i deleted and git cloned the new one down, and now i see: "raise ImportError('C extensions not built: if you installed already '
ImportError: C extensions not built: if you installed already verify that you are not importing from the source directory".  The odd thing is that pip still cannot see my NumPy when i try and `pip install pandas`.  pip and easy_install sure can see that my numpy is up to date, so i think this is a pandas issue. a shame, as i really want to get pandas working and buy your book mate.

Comment: Did you `python setup.py install` in the git clone (pandas has C extensions that must be built. also, you should not import pandas from the source directory right after installing)? If there's something wrong with your environment you should consider the 100% free Anaconda CE distribution which is bundled with everything you need.

Comment: yep i did `python setup.py install` but i did do it in the `/Library/Python/...` folder, and i did try to import right after the build. i have used `pip` to get `Cython`. what should i do instead?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the root problem (`pip install pandas` failing) on my MBP, and then tested it on another box -- the problem seems to be a conflict between the old version of numpy that comes with the mac install, and the newer one subsequently installed using `pip`. Pandas sees the old numpy, and fails.

To fix this, cd to the location of the default packages. Yours is probably the same as mine:

```
$ cd /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/ 
$ sudo rm -r numpy

$ sudo pip install pandas
```

With that out of the way, `sudo pip install pandas` worked for me on both boxes.